# How do I write a genetic algorithm to solve the knapsack problem?

Tags: genetic-algorithms, java

I am trying to write a genetic algorithm that generates 100 items, assigning random weights and utilities to them. And then try to pick items how out these 100 items while maximising the utility and not picking items over 500ks. The program should return an array of boolean values, where true represents items to be picked and false represents item not to be picked.

Can someone help with this or point me to a link of something that has been written like this before?

Comment: This is a common example of an application of genetic algorithms: showing how to solve the knapsack problem. Haven't you found anything on the web?